# Meaning of “I'm sorry for blaming you for everything I couldn't do”

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

From Christina Aguilera - "Hurt":

> I'm sorry for blaming you for everything I couldn't do.

What does it mean?

> I'm sorry for blaming you and I'm also sorry for everything I couldn't do

or

> I'm sorry that I blamed you each time I couldn't do something

Or are both possible? (I'm not a native English speaker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the latter. "I'm sorry that when I tried to do something and failed, I blamed you for it."